# How to add Pragma No-Cache to Client Object Model Request

Tags: client-object-model

In developing an application that uses the SharePoint Client Object Model, we noticed that the application is not working correctly using Safari on our iPad devices.  When testing on our desktops, we see "Pragma = no-cache" in the header made to the server and it works correctly.  The request from Safari on the iPad is missing this header.

Does anyone know if there is a way to add this in code?  One thing that seems to work is to add a datetime stamp comment in the CAML query we send.  One major issue with this approach is that not all of our requests are using CAML.

I welcome any insight.

Thanks,

Guy

Comment: Another option is to tell SharePoint/ASP.NET to never cache regardless of header values on _vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery.  What would be the .NET WCF way to configure this?

Answer (score 3):

We found that by adding a new load using a dummy CAML query with a remarked DateTime stamp  just before the executeQuery seems to solve our issue.

---EDIT---

If you're using JSOM, then just before your "ExecuteQuery" call, add something like this (note: I used a different function to get the UTC date/time):

```
var blankquery = new SP.CamlQuery();
blankquery.set_viewxml("<View><Query></Query><!--" + getUTCDate() + "--></View>");
var someList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Announcements");
var listItems = someList.getItems(blankquery);
yourContext.load(listItems, 'Include(ID)');
```

Comment: Hi Can you give me some specific steps. This would help us in fixing some issues we have in our pages